# RGB To Long To RGB

Tags: c#, rgb, long-integer

How can I convert an `Red, Green, Blue` value to a `Long` and back to `Red, Green, Blue` correctly in `C#`?

I have looked everywhere and I cannot find anything that works..

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I tried this but inside of functions:'Convert RGB to LONG:
 LONG = B * 65536 + G * 256 + R
 
'Convert LONG to RGB:
 B = LONG \ 65536
 G = (LONG - B * 65536) \ 256
 R = LONG - B * 65536 - G * 256

Comment: There are many ways of representing RGB colors in an integer (RGBx, xRGB, BGRx, RGBA, BGRA, ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public enum ColorFormat
    {
        RGB, RGBA, ARGB
    }

    public static int ColorToDecimal(Color color, ColorFormat format = ColorFormat.RGB)
    {
        switch (format)
        {
            default:
            case ColorFormat.RGB:
                return color.R << 16 | color.G << 8 | color.B;
            case ColorFormat.RGBA:
                return color.R << 24 | color.G << 16 | color.B << 8 | color.A;
            case ColorFormat.ARGB:
                return color.A << 24 | color.R << 16 | color.G << 8 | color.B;
        }
    }

    public static Color DecimalToColor(int dec, ColorFormat format = ColorFormat.RGB)
    {
        switch (format)
        {
            default:
            case ColorFormat.RGB:
                return Color.FromArgb((dec >> 16) & 0xFF, (dec >> 8) & 0xFF, dec & 0xFF);
            case ColorFormat.RGBA:
                return Color.FromArgb(dec & 0xFF, (dec >> 24) & 0xFF, (dec >> 16) & 0xFF, (dec >> 8) & 0xFF);
            case ColorFormat.ARGB:
                return Color.FromArgb((dec >> 24) & 0xFF, (dec >> 16) & 0xFF, (dec >> 8) & 0xFF, dec & 0xFF);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I call DecimalToColor because i get an error blah blah is a type but is used like a variable

Comment: I put these functions inside ```public static class ColorHelpers { }``` and call them outside like this: ```ColorHelpers.DecimalToColor(...)```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Color c = Color.FromArgb(30, 20, 120); // construct a color from RGB values
   long  redVal = c.R; //Extract Red value as long
   long greenVal = c.G;//Extract Green Value as Long
   long blueVal = c.B;//Extract Blue Value as Long
```

You can also Declare color as like the following:

```
 Color c = Color.Beige;
```

then 
**c.R=245,
c.G=245,
c.B=220**